# DropDownList with Enum Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm working on updating an application to use Kendo UI and have run into an issue with binding to an Enum with the DropDownList.  The two issues I am having is 1) the value does not contain the Enum value and instead contains "Today" (should be 0), and 2) The display value is always "Last10Days" instead of "Last 10 Days" in the description tag. I looked and couldn't find another place where someone has used Kendo UI to display the description as the text and include the numerical value instead of the text.  Any help is appreciated.

### View

```
<div class="span6">
  @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.DateRanges)
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.DateRanges)
      .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SearchDateRanges)).ToList())
      .HtmlAttributes(new { value = "Today" })
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .Events(e => e.Change("DateChange")))
</div>

<div class="span6">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Status)
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=> m.Status)
      .BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SearchStatusCriteria)).ToList())
      .HtmlAttributes(new {value = "All"}))
</div>
```

### Model

```
    public enum SearchDateRanges
{
    [Description("Today")]
    Today = 0,

    [Description("Last 10 Days")]
    Last10Days = 1,

    /// <summary>
    /// The last 30 days.
    /// </summary>
    [Description("Last 30 Days")]
    Last30Days = 2,

    [Description("Last 60 Days")]
    Last60Days = 3,

    [Description("Last 90 Days")]
    Last90Days = 4,

    [Description("Custom Date Range")]
    CustomRange = 5
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that you are asking for the Variable Name of the enum and not the description attribute:

```
.BindTo(Enum.GetNames(typeof(SearchDateRanges)).ToList())
```

To get the description attribute you'll have to do a little work.  Here is some code I found:

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
    (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
    false);

if (attributes != null &&
    attributes.Length > 0)
    return attributes[0].Description;
else
    return value.ToString();
}
```

You also are binding the Text Field to "Text" which doesn't exist in your enum.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but only binds enum values instead of Descriptions. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, this isn't supported automatically.

You can write a little helper method that takes an Enum type and converts it to a `List<SelectListItem>` like this:

```
public static List<SelectListItem> EnumToSelectList( Type enumType )
{
  return Enum
    .GetValues( enumType )
    .Cast<int>()
    .Select( i => new SelectListItem
      {
        Value = i.ToString(),
        Text = Enum.GetName( enumType, i ),
      }
    )
    .ToList()
}
```

Then you can bind your DropDownList to the Select List:

```
.BindTo( EnumToSelectList( typeof( SearchDateRanges ) ) )
```

If you want the text to come from the `Description` attributes, you'll have to modify this to get the attribute values - probably via Reflection.

Comment: Thanks, but only binds enum values instead of Descriptions. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

NET MVC 5.1 with the `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor`.

Just make a new `.cshtml` in the `Views/EditorTemplate` folder.

For example, in a cshtml with the grid,

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<NameProved.Models.Issuer>()
.Name("IssuerGrid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(issuer => issuer.ID);
    columns.Bound(issuer => issuer.Name);
    columns.Bound(issuer => issuer.IssuerType);

    columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit();
            commands.Destroy();
        }).Title("Commands");
})
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
.Editable(editable => editable
    .Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)
    )
.DataSource(datasource =>
    datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Events(events => events.Error("grid_error"))
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(issuer => issuer.ID);
        model.Field(issuer => issuer.ID).Editable(false).DefaultValue(0);
    })
    .Create(create => create.Action("Issuer_Create", "Admin"))
    .Read(read => read.Action("Issuer_Read", "Admin"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("Issuer_Update", "Admin"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Issuer_Destory", "Admin"))
    )
.Pageable()

)
)
```

Here you would have to add the `UIHint` to the `issuerType`, which is a `enum`.

Then in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplate/IssuerTypeEditor.cshtml`,

```
@model NameProved.Models.IssuerType

@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(issuerType => issuerType)
```

Then in the model, add the `UIHint`.

```
public class Issuer
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [UIHint("IssuerTypeEditor")]
    public IssuerType IssuerType { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will get it.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to avoid using UIHint by making the name of the editor template made the name of the enum exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old but in case someone googles for the same proble, here is another solution:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("subscriptionTypeTest")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .BindTo(Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(SubscriptionType)))
    .Deferred()
)
```

Comment: Side note: If using this in an Editor Template, you may have issues with .Deferred().  It took me hours to realize that was my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.NoticePeriodType)
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Value")
      .DataSource(source =>
         {
           source.Read(read =>
           {
              read.Action("LoadPeriodTypesAjax", "ControllerName"); //put controller name
            });
         })
   )


public JsonResult LoadPeriodTypesAjax()
{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PeriodType)).Cast<int>(); //PeriodType= enum name
    var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(PeriodType));
    var datas = from value in values
                select new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = converter.ConvertToString(value),
                    Value = value.ToValue(),
                };
    return Json(datas, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Answer from Andre works only with ASP.Net MVC 5.1 and above.
With older versions you can use `EnumHelper.GetSelectList`

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("subscriptionTypeTest")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .BindTo(EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(SubscriptionType)))
    .Deferred()
)
```

Comment: When you say MVC 5.1, do you mean ASP.NET Core MVC?

Comment: With MVC 5.1 I mean ASP.Net MVC 5.1 (I changed my answer). I did not test it with ASP.NET Core MVC.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to Nikolay Kostov answer. This works for Telerik asp.net core. This is the code for your editor template.

```
@model Enum

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .BindTo(Html.GetEnumSelectList<Web.Models.YourEnumType>())
        
    )
```

Comment: Tested with .Net5 - works like a charm. At least in .Net5 DataTextField() and DataValueField() are not required. BindTo honors SelectListItem enumerable returned by Html.GetEnumSelectList().

Answer (score 0):

In case you need editor template for enum in Kendo UI and ASP.NET Core, you can use this editor template code in `Enum.cshtml`:

```
@model Enum
@{
    var values = Enum.GetValues(this.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ModelType).Cast<object>()
        .Select(v => new SelectListItem
                     {
                         Selected = v.Equals(this.Model),
                         Text = v.ToString(),
                         Value = ((int)v).ToString()
                     });                               
}

@(this.Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .BindTo(values))
```